# Django rest framework is taking too long to return nested serialized data

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

We are having four models which are related, While returning queryset serializing the data is too slow(serializer.data). Below are our models and serializer.

Why django nested serializer is taking too long to return rendered response. What are we doing wrong here?

Note:Our DB lies in AWS when connected from EC2 instance it is ok but when tried from my localhost it is insanely slow. And the size of json it returns is 700KB.

models.py

```
class ServiceType(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    description = models.TextField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = 1)

class Service(models.Model):
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    service_type = models.ForeignKey(ServiceType, related_name = "type_of_service")
    min_duration = models.IntegerField() ##duration in mins

class StudioProfile(models.Model):

   studio_group = models.ForeignKey(StudioGroup, related_name = "studio_of_group")
   name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)

class StudioServices(models.Model):
   studio_profile = models.ForeignKey(StudioProfile, related_name = "studio_detail_for_activity")
   service = models.ForeignKey(Service, related_name = "service_in_studio")

class StudioPicture(models.Model):
   studio_profile  = models.ForeignKey(StudioProfile, related_name = "pic_of_studio")
   picture = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'img_gallery', null = True, blank = True)
```

serializers.py

```
class ServiceTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
       model = ServiceType
       fields = ('id', 'service_name')

class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    service_type = ServiceTypeSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Service
        fields = ('id', 'service_type', 'service_name')

class StudioServicesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    service = ServiceSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = StudioServices
        fields = ('service','price','is_active','mins_takes')

class StudioPictureSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = StudioPicture
        fields = ('picture',)

class StudioProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    studio_detail_for_activity = StudioServicesSerializer(many = True)
    pic_of_studio = StudioPictureSerializer(many = True)
    class Meta:
       model = StudioProfile
       fields = ('id', 'name','studio_detail_for_activity','pic_of_studio')
```

views.py

```
class StudioProfileView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = StudioProfileSerializer
    model = StudioProfile
    def get_queryset(self):
        try:
           queryset = self.model.objects.all()
        except Exception ,e:
           logger_error.error(traceback.format_exc())
           return None
        else:
           return queryset
```

Comment: I think if you install the `django-debug-toolbar` and look at the SQL queries you will find that you are round-tripping a lot of queries. You may be able to use `prefetch/select_related` in the ORM or a raw query to stop round-tripping related object lookups.

Comment: You can try optimizing your querysets with select_related & prefetch_related. 

If you can use caching it will provide quite the performance boon.

Answer (score 2):

Did you checked which part is the slow one? like, How many records do you have in that db? and I would try to run the query and check if the query is slow, then I'd check the serializers with less than 100 registers and so on.

I'd recommend you to read this article http://www.dabapps.com/blog/api-performance-profiling-django-rest-framework/ in order to evaluate how to profile your API

Regards

Comment: Am having 150 studios each having around 100 services for them. It is slowing down While executing  return Response(serializer.data)

Comment: That's a great article, but instead of inserting timers one can use django-debug-toolbar to show where the most expensive queries exist.